Сделать зум при наведении мышкой на PictureBox [Доработка]
Начнём с кода:
private void PictureBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;

    zoomedForm = new Form();
    zoomedForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    zoomedForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    zoomedForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    zoomedForm.Size = new Size(300, 300); // Размер всплывающего окна
    zoomedForm.TopMost = true;

    zoomedPictureBox = new PictureBox();
    zoomedPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    zoomedPictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    zoomedForm.Controls.Add(zoomedPictureBox);

    zoomedForm.Show();
}

private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateZoomedImage();
}

private void PictureBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (zoomedForm != null)
    {
        zoomedForm.Close();
        zoomedForm.Dispose();
    }
}

private void UpdateZoomedImage()
{
    if (zoomedForm != null)
    {
        PictureBox pb = mainPictureBox;

        // Получение текущих координат мыши на экране
        Point mouseLocation = Control.MousePosition;
        // Вычисление масштабного коэффициента для корректного отображения увеличенной части изображения
        float scaleX = (float)pb.Image.Width / pb.ClientSize.Width;
        float scaleY = (float)pb.Image.Height / pb.ClientSize.Height;
        // Определение координат увеличенной части изображения с учетом масштабирования
        int zoomedWidth = (int)(pb.Width * 0.10 * scaleX);
        int zoomedHeight = (int)(pb.Height * 0.10 * scaleY);

        int zoomedX = (int)((mouseLocation.X - pb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).X - zoomedWidth / 2) * scaleX);
        int zoomedY = (int)((mouseLocation.Y - pb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).Y - zoomedHeight / 2) * scaleY);

        // Создание нового Bitmap для увеличенной части изображения
        Bitmap zoomedImage = new Bitmap(zoomedWidth, zoomedHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(zoomedImage))
        {
            g.DrawImage(pb.Image, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, zoomedImage.Size), zoomedX, zoomedY, zoomedWidth, zoomedHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        // Установка увеличенной части изображения в PictureBox на всплывающем окне
        zoomedPictureBox.Image = zoomedImage;
        // Получение текущего экрана, на котором находится курсор мыши
        Screen currentScreen = Screen.FromPoint(mouseLocation);

        // Установка положения всплывающего окна
        int zoomedPictureBoxWidth = zoomedPictureBox.Image.Width * 2;
        int zoomedPictureBoxHeight = zoomedPictureBox.Image.Height * 2;
        Point newLocation = new Point(mouseLocation.X + 20, mouseLocation.Y - zoomedPictureBoxHeight - 40);
        if (newLocation.X + zoomedForm.Width > currentScreen.Bounds.Right) // При достижении правого края экрана
            newLocation.X = currentScreen.Bounds.Right - zoomedForm.Width;
        if (newLocation.Y < currentScreen.Bounds.Top) // При достижении верхнего края экрана
            newLocation.Y = currentScreen.Bounds.Top;
        if (newLocation.Y + zoomedPictureBoxHeight > currentScreen.Bounds.Bottom) // При достижении нижнего края экрана
            newLocation.Y = currentScreen.Bounds.Bottom - zoomedPictureBoxHeight;

        // Установка положения всплывающего окна
        zoomedForm.Location = newLocation;

        // Установка размеров формы в соответствии с размерами увеличенной части изображения, решает проблему с белыми полями (т.к zoomedPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;)
        zoomedForm.Size = new Size(zoomedPictureBoxWidth, zoomedPictureBoxHeight);
    }
}

Я реализовал функцию зума при наведении мышкой на picturebox. Рядом с мышкой появляется новая форма (zoomedForm) и уже в ней отрисовывается приближенное изображение, всё работает хорошо но есть
проблема:
При изменении размеров формы (PictureBox внутри формы в состоянии dock - fill) picturebox конечно-же меняет размеры и логика приближения ломается т.е мышка в одном месте а зазумленая область (в zoomForm) уже в другом месте.
Проще говоря рассинхрон координат фактического места откуда должно быть зазумлено изображение и фактического местоположения мыши. Как можно решить данную проблему?
